# Define directive in child component and call it in parent component Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, components, directive

I have a custom Button component with custom `style` directive (v-style) to add some classes:

```js
directives: {
        style: {
            bind(el, binding) {
                const style = binding.value;

                if (!["primary", "success", "error"].includes(style)) {
                    throw new TypeError(`Button style ${style} not valid`);
                }

                el.classList.add(`button-${style}`);
            }
        }
    }
```

And in the parent component I want to use that directive this way:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <Button v-style="'primary'">Send</Button>
    </div>
</template>
```

But it's not working. Should I create a global directive and check for the element is bound or there is a better way?

```js
Vue.directive("style", {...});
```

Comment: Why don't you put it inside the `Button` component where the button is? you cannot treat a custom component as a native one.

Comment: I called component AppButton to prevent mixing with html element. I want directive be only available to AppButton component, but use it in all components.